# When you back up a database and scripts are running at the same time, at what point in time does the backup reflect?

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

If I run a SQL Server database backup via Management Studio and there are scripts running at the same time, does the backup reflect the point in time when the backup was started or when it ended? My db is about 10GB so the backup takes some time, meaning there's lots of things that could go on in the meantime.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Now I also asked in [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14381/when-you-back-up-a-database-and-scripts-are-running-at-the-same-time-at-what-po). 
(Should this question just be removed/moved/what?)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/100490/what-happens-during-a-live-sql-server-backup

Comment: Please don't cross post. Ask a mod to migrate. Thanks.

Comment: When starting backup  a database, SQL Server will ask the OS to create a snapshot of the database. Then the SQL server will take backup of the database data from the snapshot. The DB changes will occur in the database are which won't affect the snapshot. Once the backup operation is completed, the changes will be merged with the main database.

Comment: @Aravind: that's not at all what's happening. Where are you getting your info from? Snapshots are used for instance in checkdb, but not in backup. Snapshots are not an OS feature, they are a SQL feature that relies on sparse files (an OS feature). All in all, a lot of misinformation in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full backup includes the image of each allocated data page in the database *and* all the log that was generated from the moment the backup started until the backup finished all the data pages copy.

At restore time the data is copied out *and* the log is copied out and laid out on disk. If the RESTORE command was issued as `WITH RECOVERY` (default) then normal recovery is run on the database, meaning the log is replayed. This brings the database back into a consistent state. If the RESTORE was issued `WITH NORECOVERY` then the log and data are left 'as is' and the database can accept more log to be restored, copied out from other LOG backup(s) into the LDF file(s). Eventually, when the database is recovered, it is brought back into  consistent state. See [Restore and Recovery Overview (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455.aspx).